# Toggle between two colors in a common-cathode RGB LED using a SPST switch

Tags: led, switching, rgb

I'm working on a switching circuit for a guitar amplifier that uses one DPDT relay which is powered by 12V DC supply. A SPST switch (panel mount or footswitch) will power the relay and switch to a second amplifier channel.

Is it possible to wire a common-cathode RGB LED to glow one color (red) when relay is off and other color (blue) when relay is on?

The closest circuit I could find is this [Alternating between two LEDS using BJTs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/121038/alternating-between-two-leds-using-bjts)
but it has common anodes.

Is it possible to rework the circuit to use common cathodes?

If that's possible, I could bring a positive voltage to R4 when I turn the relay on.

Comment: That question you linked has a mixture of solutions, some are common cathode and some are common anode. The one in the question itself is common cathode.

Comment: If red is permanently on, switching green gives you red and yellow.

Comment: Note there are also exist bi-colored LEDs which may save some space in case needed (these have 3 pins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch high side you can use a P-MOSFET as shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi55C6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As others have mentioned, a simpler solution is simply to mix the colours.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKKN1U.png)</sup>

Comment: thanks! Switching between red and blue is what I need (i.e. without mixing colors). The solution with mosfet seems like the one to use then. One question, how does turning the second LED on make the first LED go off? It still seems to be connected to the +ve supply.

Comment: @BranislavStojkovic the left led is only on if the switch is closed. and will be pulled down through the relay when the switch is open. That turns on the mosfet which lights the other LED.

Comment: @BranislavStojkovic please not I changed the resistors in the first schematic. This is important to prevent the left diode from being back biased when the MOSFET is on. It also lets you set the brightness of each colour separately.

Comment: thanks for the update, good to know. I just need to find a P-MOSFET and will breadboard it. I think that only one store in my city carries BS250 and that's about it when it comes to P-MOSFETS :)

Comment: Hi Trevor. I managed to find only BS208 and wired it according to your first schematic. However, when I flick the switch it seems to be turning the second LED on without shutting the first LED off. If I make blue LED the second one, it can overpower the red LED and make it barely visible, but it kind of defeats the purpose of the MOSFET. Do you have any idea what could have gone wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @BranislavStojkovic with the switch open second led should be on, first one off. CLosing the switch first led should be on second off. NOt sure what you mean.

Comment: Looks like I wired the MOSFET reversed. It works as expected after I flipped it around. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @BranislavStojkovic I was wondering about that ;)

Comment: Just for my education, would a P-JFET work here, like J175?

Comment: Not really, jfets only operate in depletion mode, this mosfet is working in enhancement mode. There are other differences too www.circuitstoday.com/jfet-and-mosfet-comparison

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to have two different colours depending on whether a SPST switch is on, the simplest possible way is to have one on permanently and one switched, giving you either red or yellow. This answers the question as written. Trevor's answer would work to give one on or the other on (without mixing colours), which may be what you meant, however requires more complexity and components.

[image: schematic]

Answer (score 0):

This trick is based on differences in the forward voltages of the diodes, which are mostly unknown so far.  If the forward voltage of D3 is less than the combined Vf of D1 and D4, then when the switch closes, D3 will come on and D1 will go off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6xkoS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: duplicate answer

Answer (score 0):

This trick is based on differences in the forward voltages of the diodes, which are mostly unknown so far.  If the forward voltage of D3 is less than the combined Vf of D1 and D4, then when the switch closes, D3 will come on and D1 will go off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKn2zA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I'd be concerned about the reverse voltage on D3 at 12V supply with this one though.